# How to use tel: with * (star, asterisk) or # (hash, pound) on iOS?

Tags: html, ios, url-scheme, phone-call

I'm trying to initiate a call on the iPhone with the `tel` url that has a * in it. It properly brings up the call dialog but drops back to safari when you click call.

```
<a href="tel:123*12">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[This documentation from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html) should be helpful:

> **To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing the behavior of a phone or account, the Phone application
>   supports most, but not all, of the special characters in the tel
>   scheme. Specifically, if a URL contains the * or # characters, the
>   Phone application does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone
>   number.**

**UPDATE (Jan 2, 2018)**: The information mentioned here may be outdated. Please refer to new documentation if Apple has relaxed these rules in their newer SDKs. Refer to Husam's answer.

Comment: **iOS 11 allows calling `*` or  `#`**, read my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47062700/1599713

Answer (score 11):

**iOS11** now allows us to call number with `*` or `#`

---

### Swift Example code

```swift
let number = "*111*12345#"
let app = UIApplication.shared
if let encoded = number.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed) {
    let u = "tel://\(encoded)"
    if let url = URL(string:u) {
        if app.canOpenURL(url) {
            app.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: { (finished) in
                
            })
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How? Using iOS11, Xcode 9.2, Swift 4.0.3, I'm unable to dial a number with # and *.

Comment: Thanks, Husam! I was encoding the entire string (tel://*111*12345#). The key was to *only* encode the *number*, not the `tel://` prefix.

Answer (score 5):

The approved answer is not correct, at least anymore. I've tested both as a [web page](https://stephenschale.com/phones.html) and in app being able to dial using the special character `#` and `*`. What you do have to do if you wish to use those characters in either instance though is to encode them.

In HTML, `#` becomes `%23` and `*` does not need to be escaped

If using Swift, you can encode your link and press it from an app using this function:

```swift
//number format example (commas are pauses): 123-456-7890,,555#,1234
fileprivate func callNumber(_ number: String) {
    let dialString = "telprompt://" + number
    if let escapedDialString = dialString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed) {
      if let dialURL = URL(string: escapedDialString) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(dialURL)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: can we open dial pad from my app. string like *123456#. I have tried with above answers, but its not working. Please help me its very urgent.

Comment: See [@Husam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47062700/1107226). Husam's example code does, indeed, work on iOS 11. The trick is to encode *only* the number portion, not the `tel://` portion. (Also not that `telprompt://` is no longer needed to get the call confirmation prompt. `tel://` will now do the same.)

Comment: I think you just need .open() not .openURL

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add * to href typed as "tel" you need to use the utf-8 encoded version - %2A

Reference :  [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)

For example

```html
<a href="tel:%2A1234"> Phone me <a/>
```