# Iphone How to make a call that includes pauses and # to dial conf numbers

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem using tel: with * (star, asterisk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660951/problem-using-tel-with-star-asterisk)

I am building an application that needs to dial conference numbers (919-900-9000,,,1234#).  The commas are pauses and the # is entered after the password.  I have tried to use the NSURL but this strips out any special characters including * and #.  Is there another way to make a call programmatically on the Iphone?

Comment: See this (duplicate) for an answer on how to do this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795457/how-to-dial-a-phone-number-with/13198801#13198801

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot.  To prevent third-party app from dialing phone numbers that can cost the user money, iOS blocks those options.  Basically the user has to take responsibility and dial the conference number themselves.