# IOS How to make phone call with nondigits

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to dial a phone number with “##”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795457/how-to-dial-a-phone-number-with)

I am having troble making a phone call with * and #

ex: "** 002 ** 5555555555"

At the moment i am using URL schemes ex: *tel:+5555555555*

Comment: also tried http://forums.adobe.com/message/4157305?tstart=0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wanted to do this, too. There's no way. It's explicitly disallowed by Apple for security reasons:

> To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing the behavior of a phone or account, the Phone application supports most, but not all, of the special characters in the `tel` scheme. Specifically, if a URL contains the `*` or `#` characters, the Phone application does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number.

Source:

- [Apple URL Scheme Reference: Phone Links](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html)

Comment: Is there an alternative to URL schemes? And would that allow me to make such a call?

Comment: No, that's how you place a call. This isn't an oversight; it's explicitly disallowed for security reasons. You're not going to find a way around it.

Comment: @StevenFisher is correct, when i face this problem, i have just copy the number into clipboard programatically and insist user to open dial pad and paste the number and make call.. :)

Comment: That's a clever hack, KingofBliss. Thanks for suggesting it. :)