# How to open the ios Native dialer app from my App

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl, phone-number, ussd

I want to open the native dialer app and allow the user to enter the phone number there. The reason why i want this is because in my app the user needs to use USSD codes in order to make calls, but using the code bellow nothing happens (nothing is started)

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:number]; 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

I read here (StackOverflow) that making calls from your app that contain * and # are forbidden.
So i want to ask is there any work around this limitation.

Comment: `NSString *phoneNumber = [@"telprompt://" stringByAppendingString:@number];` Worked for me

Comment: He is referring to the symbols, not whether or not the syntax is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no workaround with those symbols.

Comment: Can I open dialler app from my app (with a number without special char)?

Answer (score 0):

Well i was looking for the same some time ago, i found out that the emulators has problem doing this kind of thing, you should try on a real devices.

Edit from [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH6-SW1):

> To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing
>   the behavior of a phone or account, the Phone app supports most, but
>   not all, of the special characters in the tel scheme. Specifically, if
>   a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone app does not attempt
>   to dial the corresponding phone number.  If your app receives URL
>   strings from the user or an unknown source,  you should also make sure
>   that any special characters that might not be appropriate in a URL are
>   escaped properly.

Also written in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10796546/3630157) post

Comment: I am testing this on real device (iPhone4 - iOS 7, iPhone5 - iOS 8, iPhone6 - iOS 8), and if the number does not contain * or # the dialer is started, but those characters are contained nothing happens

Comment: Ty for the -1 but if you don't give those informations it's hard to help, by the way searching around i think i found out the same post that you did saying that "making calls from your app that contain * and # are forbidden". Sorry i don't know any workaround..