# How can I open a call panel from an app programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In my country *135*phonenumber# --> thats mean you should call me and i dont have money you pay this conversation. I need this type in call panel. But programmatically... [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1b6A2_GrQBYem5xSEctN1NPN0FjdlJTZ05fc1RyVlBBeXNz/view)?

Comment: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:55698"]];`

Comment: i tried this but i need * and # symbols inside phone number. But does not accept...

Comment: That cannot be done. Please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27224480/how-to-open-the-ios-native-dialer-app-from-my-app).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584663/programatically-dial-a-phone-number-and-pass-dtmf-using-the-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add '*' or '#' to the tel:// scheme to make a call from the app...

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10796546/4236572