# How do I include # in tel:123#?

Tags: html, mobile, tel

How do I populate a '#' in a mobile browser auto-dialer using tel:123#?

ex:

```
<a href='tel:123#'>Dial this number</a>
```

This will only populate '123' in the native auto-dialer. Any way to include the # in the dialer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660951/how-to-use-tel-with-star-asterisk-or-hash-pound-on-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have the same issue on android, not only on iphone, and I have solved (at least for Android) by escaping the string:

```
<button class="phoneCallButton">click me and call an hash number</button>

$(document).ready(function(){ 


  $(".phoneCallButton").click( function()
           {

             window.location = 'tel:'+escape("*123#");
           }
    );
});
```

Comment: iphone doesn't permit to send # anymore :/

Answer (score 3):

You can't, see [How to use tel: with * (star, asterisk) or # (hash, pound) on iOs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4661050/416791)

---

[Apple Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html) should be helpful.

> To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing
>   the behavior of a phone or account, the Phone application supports
>   most, but not all, of the special characters in the tel scheme.
>   **Specifically, if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone
>   application does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number.**