# click to call tel: link do not send the '#' symbol

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, symbols, phone-number, tel

I'm having trouble to make a tel: link that sends a specific code: `*1#`

the link is a normal tel: link:

```
<button class="call">send the code</button>
<script>
$(".call").click( function()
       {
         window.location = "tel:*1#";
       }
);
</script>
```

The `*` are sent right, but when the phone number pops up, here is no `#` symbol.

I have tried to escape it with `%23` (instead of `#`), but nothing, I see `%23` in the link. Any idea?

Comment: @putvande - may be its like a balance checker or a data usage checker *123# something like that.

Comment: it is a code, it has to be dialed by the phone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using an iphone - this is an exerpt from apple help

> To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing the behavior of a
>   phone or account, the Phone application supports most, but not all, of the special 
>   characters in the tel scheme. Specifically, if a URL contains the * or # characters, the 
>   Phone application does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number.

They relaxed it on the `*` but not on the hash - it is annoying I know!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660951/how-to-use-tel-with-star-asterisk-or-hash-pound-on-ios

Answer (score 4):

Android will let you call with special characters in the link, but iOS will not.

The closest you can get to auto-populating the dial pad with special characters is to use the URL encoding format:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

%23 is the character for #