# tel: & callto html not working with iphone for service numbers like *000#

Tags: ios, iphone, html, mobile

Hi I'm trying to make mobile website that contains service link as the following:

```
<a href="tel:*000#">*000#</a>
```

I tried to encode the special characters & htmlentetries with no results, The call box appears but there is no action after you click call.

Comment: This smells like something that may be blocked for security purposes. I'm sure this could be misused for harmful things somehow (like network specific codes changing something about the phone's service.)

Comment: Thank you Pekka, but do you have something documented from apple for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use tel: with \* (star, asterisk) or # (hash, pound) on iOs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660951/how-to-use-tel-with-star-asterisk-or-hash-pound-on-ios)

Answer (score 1):

The tel: URI scheme (as well as sms: but also feed:, maps:, youtube: and others) is handled by protocol handlers (as mailto: and http: are).

Here is a simple example:

```
<a href="tel:+15555551212">Call us free!</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's documentation:

> To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing the behavior of a phone or account, the Phone app supports most, but not all, of the special characters in the tel scheme. Specifically, if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone app does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html