# Dialing a number with # in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I want to make a button in Xcode that dials *133#, and i have seen that is restricted by apple, is there is a way to do something about it, is there a way to contact apple for support because i really make this app for a good use.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660951/how-to-use-tel-with-star-asterisk-or-hash-pound-on-ios%20you%20can) you can't. I don't think you can do something about it. You can try to contact them, but I doubt that they change their mind. They have a good reason to block that (taken from answer in question linked):

> To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing the behavior of a phone or account ... if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone application does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number.