# How can I call to phone number with * or # character

Tags: ios, swift, phone-number, phone-call

I need to call to a "*105" number, but when I tried to call, nothing's going on. Also alertController not showing.. How can I call to a phone number with * or # signs?

Here is my code:

```
    var url = NSURL(string: "tel://*105")

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url! as URL)
    {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url! as URL)
    }
    else
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "You can't to call.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: this is not currently possible with apple https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html

Comment: It is is possible, you need to use `telprompt`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660951/how-to-use-tel-with-star-asterisk-or-hash-pound-on-ios/42448535#42448535