# Can't create URL from string with '#' in the middle

Tags: swift, ios11, tel

Issue explained through code.

```
    let u = "tel://*111*11111111111#" //Works perfectly on iOS11 and later
    let u = "tel://*111#11111111111#" //Doesn't work, Can't create URL

    let app = UIApplication.shared
    if let url = URL(string:u) {
        if app.canOpenURL(url) {
            app.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: { (finished) in 
            })
        }
    }
```

** If I encode the string then `canOpenURL()` fails !

Comment: Phone numbers with hash or asterisk characters may not be allowed in urls: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660951/how-to-use-tel-with-star-asterisk-or-hash-pound-on-ios

Comment: Yes, but In iOS 11 It's allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `URLComponents`. Handles percent escapes automatically for you and everything.

```
var comps = URLComponents()

comps.scheme = "tel"
comps.host = "*111#11111111111#"

print(comps.url!) // prints "tel://*111%2311111111111%23"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem fixed**,

Number should be encoded separately without `tel://`

```
let u = "tel://*111#11111111111#"
if let encoded = u.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed) {
    let u = "tel://\(encoded)"
    if let url = URL(string:u) {
        if app.canOpenURL(url) {
            app.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: { (finished) in
                
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the call work even though you're percent-escaping the hash? The final URL will be `tel://tel%3A%2F%2F*111%2311111111111%23`.

Comment: Yes worked, the call prompt decoded the url automatically

Comment: IMO, `URLComponents` is a simpler and cleaner way to do this. `URLComponents` is also more up to date, since it conforms to RFC 3986, unlike `URL(string:)` which the documentation states to conform to older RFCs.

Comment: Why does the initial value of `u` contain `tel://`? Just encode actual number, not the scheme. And `tel` URLs do not use the `//`.