# URL with string tel://*#06# is returning nil in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the below code in Swift 4.x:

```
let url = URL(string: "tel://*#06#")
```

This gives url as nil. Just this particular number has some problem. Can someone tell me how to solve this and why is this even a problem in the first place.

Comment: This answer might be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660951/how-to-use-tel-with-star-asterisk-or-hash-pound-on-ios/47062700#47062700

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use tel: with \* (star, asterisk) or # (hash, pound) on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660951/how-to-use-tel-with-star-asterisk-or-hash-pound-on-ios)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html) :

> To prevent users from maliciously redirecting phone calls or changing the behavior of a phone or account, the Phone app supports most, but not all, of the special characters in the tel scheme. Specifically, **if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone app does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number.**

Please note that for other characters, you can use `addingPercentEncoding` method to escape special characters which returns a properly escaped version of your original string.

Example:

```
let encoding = phoneNumberString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Ketan Ordera suggested even after you prperaed your URL using URLEncoding, you cannot run USSD code in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

To make a call use the next function:

```
 static func callPhone (phone:String){

        guard let number = URL(string: "telprompt://" + phone) else { return }
        UIApplication.shared.open(number)
    }
```