# Phone dialer issues in xamarin.plugins.messaging

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I am new for Xamarin and I just wanted to directly make a phone call from my Xamarin app.
I just wanted to include the hashtag(#) symbol in the phone number as a string, but it doesn't include the symbol when the program is executed.

Here is the code,

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var phoneDialer = CrossMessaging.Current.PhoneDialer;
            if (phoneDialer.CanMakePhoneCall)
                phoneDialer.MakePhoneCall("*999#");
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660951/how-to-use-tel-with-star-asterisk-or-hash-pound-on-ios/4661050):

> Specifically, if a URL contains the * or # characters, the Phone
>   application does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number.

There is also an answer in Swift which says `iOS11 now allows us to call number with * or #` , I translate it to C# and you can have a try with dependency service:

In `shared Project`:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DependencyService.Get<IPhoneCallTask>().DoPhoneCall();
    }
}

public interface IPhoneCallTask
{
    void DoPhoneCall();
}
```

In `iOS Project`:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(phoneCall))]
namespace App591.iOS
{
    class phoneCall : IPhoneCallTask
    {
        public void DoPhoneCall()
        {
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
            {
                NSString number = new NSString("*111*12345#");

                NSString encode = number.CreateStringByAddingPercentEncoding(NSUrlUtilities_NSCharacterSet.UrlHostAllowedCharacterSet);
                NSString header = new NSString("tel://");
                string tmp = string.Format("{0}{1}", encode, header);
                NSString urlTemp = new NSString(tmp);

                if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(new Uri(urlTemp)))
                {
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new Uri(urlTemp));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```